# Создание папки\файла с текущей датой

Tags: c++

Мне нужно, чтобы программа создавала папку с текущей датой, установленной на ПК.
Вот код, который я написал, и сообщение об ошибке, которая возникает в результате выполнения кода.

```
#include "time.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
char buffer[80];
char* filename ( )
{
    time_t timess;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &timess );
    char *buff2 = buffer;
    timeinfo = localtime ( &timess );
    strftime ( buff2, 80, "%y%m%d%", timeinfo );
    strcat ( buff2, ".txt" );
    return ( buff2 );
}
```

> Ошибка    1   error C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.    f:\документы\visual studio 2013\projects\main\time file creator\main.cpp   12  1   time file creator

Скажите, что я делаю не так? И по возможности, опишите, как сделать, чтобы с другой папки, все файлы, которые находятся в ней, перемещались в эту папку автоматически? (и только 1 тип файла оставляли)

Пишите подробно, т.к. я ещё новичок в этом.

Comment: Не нужно ссылок на код во внешних источниках. Размещайте его прямо тут, в вопросе. Для форматирования можно использовать разметку Markdown: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Компилятор говорит, что использование localtime небезопасно, чтобы проигнорировать добавьте дифайн _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS или используйте функцию localtime_s.

Comment: Хорошо, в будущем буду сюда все выкладывать.

Comment: Я пробовал дописывать в начало программы  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS , тоже самое было. Использовал localtime_s была другая ошибка. "Ошибка 1 error C2660: localtime_s: функция не принимает 1 аргументов"

Comment: Можно `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` написать в самом верху, до включения других файлов (`#include "time.h"`), а `localtime_s` действительно требует два аргумента, посмотрите в справочнике какие.

Comment: Попробовал добавить в начале кода ту строчку, пишет теперь другое - `error LNK1561: точка входа должна быть определена` .

Comment: Переменная `char *buff2` здесь избыточна, можно вместо неё сразу использовать `buffer`.

Comment: `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` можно в настройках проекта ещё задать, глобально.

Comment: Ну и `strcat` не очень безопасно выглядит. Хоть у вас и вроде буфер достаточного размера, но в будущем все может поменяться, и может быть переполнение.

Comment: Я если честно, ничего не понял... Ладно, суть исправления я этой ошибки понял, пойду у гугла спрошу, что да как. Спасибо!

Comment: Что-то немного тут от `c++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не ошибка, это предупреждение: вы используете потенциально небезопасную функцию...

Если вы понимаете, что делаете, и берете на себя ответственность - игнорируйте предупреждение (или определите этот макрос, который просят).

Или пользуйтесь функциями `_s` - той же [`localtime_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a442x3ye.aspx), в которую действительно надо передавать два параметра - указатели на `tm` и `time_t`.

Примерно так:

```
char buffer[80];
char* filename()
{
    time_t timess;
    struct tm timeinfo;
    time(&timess);
    char *buff2 = buffer;
    localtime_s(&timeinfo, &timess);
    strftime(buff2, 80, "%Y%m%d", &timeinfo);
    strcat_s(buff2, 80, ".txt");
    return (buff2);
}


int main()
{
    cout << "start\n";
    cout << filename() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это ошибка, посмотрите внимательнее на текст. Студия считает, что она имеет права давать такие ошибки

Comment: @ixSci Не стоит ли просто настройка "трактовать все предупреждения как ошибки"? У меня при ключике `/W4` дает просто как Warning.

Comment: У меня на 2015 студии без WX и с W3 даёт именно ошибку. Причём 2, ещё одну на `strcat`

Comment: Нашёл причину — ключ /sdl

Comment: Ну, этот код у меня заработал без ошибок, и предупреждений. Хотелось бы узнать, как теперь то файл создавать при помощи всего этого? У меня только текущую дату.txt пишет, а нигде ничего не создает...

Comment: @Bagger Ну, файл просто открываете для записи - типа `ofstream of(name);`, каталог - `_mkdir(name);`

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!